# Protected Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am faced an already developed application from a customer written in Ruby on Rails. I just see app directory, and the controllers folder is empty.

The file `config.ru` loads a Gem that isn’t listed in the Gemfile. The server is a `cPanel`, potentially a VPS or Cloud Server.

The company who developed the website take measures to avoid code modification? How this is done?

I can’t change the source at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file config.ru loads a Gem that isn’t listed in the Gemfile. The
>   server is a cPanel, potentially a VPS or Cloud Server.

I don’t think this was done to deliberately hide the Ruby Gem.

That said, Ruby Gem setups like this drive me nuts.

What most likely has happened is the development firm developed the code as a Ruby Gem for their own ease of development. Sorry to say, Ruby developers love using Gems even when they are not really not needed. Like using a nail gun when a hammer works well. Meaning, the Ruby Gem in question is most likely a simple Ruby library.

And the benefit of installing a system-wide Ruby Gem is you can access your custom libraries without having to specify a full path to the file.

The negative is you need to install the Ruby Gem as an administrator. And because the library might be fragmented from your main codebase, development might entail juggling multiple codebases. Which can be confusing when dealing with simple tasks.

I’m saying all of this because I recently had to refactor code that was unnecessarily placed in a Ruby Gem so it could be placed in a standard `lib/` directory right next to the `config.ru`. Which makes debugging & development tons easier. All of the code and idiosyncratic libraries are right there in front of whoever needs to work with the code. Which makes everyone’s life easier.

Do you know what the name of the Gem is? If not, login to the server on the command line and run this command:

```
gem query --local
```

That will give you a list of all locally installed Ruby Gems—including version numbers—which should be a big help to you in this task.

And do you know which version of Ruby is being used for the Ruby Gem and related application? If not, just run this to get the version:

```
ruby --version
```

Chances are it is in a directory like this; using an Ubuntu 12.04 setup with Ruby 1.9.1 installed as an example:

```
ls -la /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/
```

Of course `1.9.1` should be changed to whatever version of Ruby is being used for the Ruby Gem and related application. So check in the parent directory:

```
ls -la /var/lib/gems/
```

Then if you know the name of the Ruby Gem installed you can then look into the contents of that Ruby Gem like this:

```
ls -la /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/name-of-the-gem/
```

Of course, `name-of-the-gem` is the actual name of the Ruby Gem in question.

You should be able to simply look into that directory & see the Ruby files that comprise that Ruby Gem right there. You know why? Ruby Gems are just packages of Ruby files neatly placed in one package. Nothing more. Nothing less.

At this point you could actually copy the code in the Ruby Gem and see if you can place it locally like I have done in the refactoring I mentioned above.

Comment: Turns out that I couldn't even login to the server neither access a PHP shell backdoor that I uploaded through FTP.
I just wonder how the Ruby (and Rails) know how to run with a empty controller folder. Maybe the guy just made an user and put some random code there to fool the customer. But your answer is wonderful, thanks for your help!